# Cordova Camera App on iOS do nothing

Tags: iphone, cordova, camera

This is my first message on this site.

I've created a Cordova project to use iPhone camera. I used the full example on [cordova site](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/cordova/camera/camera.getPicture.html#page-toc-source) with no modification.

But when I click on any of the button, nothing happen.
No message is displayed, no notification from iOS to allow the usage of the camera and no message in Safari web inspector on the Mac linked to the phone.

I'm using :

> Cordova 6.4.0, IOS platform 4.3.0, Camera 2.3.0 IOS 9.3.5 or 8.1

Comment: Why are you using a very, very old documentation? On top of the page is an extra warning for that. Here you find the right one: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html

Comment: I'll look at that option when I'll be back to my desk. Thanks